# applying padding after using css reset

Tags: css

As it turns out I don't know CSS.

I ran into a brick wall after using Eric Meyer's CSS reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

I have a table with this style

```
table.home_right_top, .home_right_top table, .home_right_top
{
background-color: #F2F2F2;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
}
```

but the padding is not applied to the table at all and I cannot figure out why. I am happy that I see the same behavior on all the browsers including IE7 and IE8 but I don't see any padding. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is my table

```
<table class="home_right_top" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="blueHeading14 heading_padding_right" style="width: 64px">Products</td>
            <td class="rpt_stroke" style="width: 280px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we see your html for the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the last line in his css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Try removing that and seeing what happens, table cells don't often act like `block` level elements. I think the real problem here is that you shouldn't style the table element like this, becasue it's display property by default is `table` which is not the same as the box model.

Try putting padding on the cells themselves or add a margin to the table.

Comment: I think I pretty much said what @mVChr said no?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the reset, it's that the W3 CSS property spec states that `padding` can be applied to:

> all elements except table-row-group,
>   table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-row,
>   table-column-group and table-column

So it's invalid to apply `padding` to a `<table>`.  Instead, the only solution that comes to mind is to apply `margin` instead, wrap the table in a `<div>`, or apply the padding to the individual `<td>`s with special classes.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Did you declare a DocType?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the style to the TD's not the table.

```
    table.home_right_top td
```